# Can't mass-assign protected attributes with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've used nested attributes and form_for before, but am just missing something simple. Here are my models...

## skill.rb

```
class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag
  attr_accessible :tag_id, :user_id, :weight
end
```

## tag.rb

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :skills
  attr_accessible :name, :skills_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :skills
end
```

## app/views/tags/_form.html.erb

```
 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <%= f.fields_for :skill do |s| %>
    <%= s.label :weight %><br />
    <%= s.text_field :weight %>
  <% end %>
```

The parms for both models are being passed OK, but I'm getting a mass assignmnet error in the console...

```
Started POST "/tags" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-26 10:13:51 -0400
Processing by TagsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"yofQhmgOyNHvnws/Lg+BoS4TqeTwPdyQjQbLXotnEzI=", "tag"=>{"name"=>"test", "skill"=>{"weight"=>"ee"}}, "commit"=>"Create Tag"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: skill):
  app/controllers/tags_controller.rb:43:in `new'
  app/controllers/tags_controller.rb:43:in `create'
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: is there anything special at tags_controller.rb:43? also what happens when you try 'mass-assigning' Skill directly?

Comment: Line 43 is just the creation action...with @tag = Tag.new(params[:tag])

Comment: Show us the params :).

Comment: `fields_for :skills`, not `:skill`.

Comment: If you use plural :skills, then the label/test field do not display in the form. Only singular allows the field to be displayed. Params look correct   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"yofQhmgOyNHvnws/Lg+BoS4TqeTwPdyQjQbLXotnEzI=", "tag"=>{"name"=>"test", "skill"=>{"weight"=>"33"}}, "commit"=>"Create Tag"}

Answer (score 1):

In tag.rb, make the skill attribute accessible.

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :skills
  attr_accessible :name, :skills_attributes, :skill
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :skills
end
```

Comment: If I do this I get unknown attribute: skill. Adding :skills_attributes should give tag the appropriate access to the stills attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following to handle the has_many:

```
    <% @tag.skills.each do |skill| %>
        <%= f.fields_for :skills, skill do |s| %>
            <%= s.label :weight %><br />
            <%= s.text_field :weight %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

In controller new/edit:

```
    @tag.skills.build if @tag.skills.empty?
```

Comment: I edited my answer to add a line that may be needed in the controller.  If that doesn't fix it, I'm definitely confused, too.

Answer (score 1):

Jeremy Pinnix answer above is correct, just you also need to change your View code:

```
 <%= f.fields_for :skills do |s| %>
   <%= s.label :weight %><br />
   <%= s.text_field :weight %>
 <% end %>
```

You should refer to your fields_for association in the plural. ie skills not skill.

Comment: If you use plural :skills, then the label/test field do not display in the form. Only singular allows the field to be displayed.